# Problems displaying a location and centering the camera on it

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation, locationmanager

I've just had some issues for odd reasons with the CameraUpdateFactory.

So I incorporated this code in an onclickListener on the GpsButton on a navigation fragment:

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mapFragment.getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d("Permission checked", "checkSelfPermission passed with no errors");
                map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                Log.d("Permission checked", "Location Layer implementation successful");
            } else {
                //Request the Permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mapFragment.getActivity(), new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
            }
```

This basically enables the location to be displayed as a blue dot on the map only when the GPS button is pressed. This has been perfectly functional so far.

I also incorporated a method to move the camera to my current location:

```
 public void locateMe() {

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE); // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();// Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);// Getting the name of the best provider
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mapFragment.getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mapFragment.getActivity(), new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 2);
    }
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (location != null) {

        double latitude = location.getLatitude(); //Getting latitude of the current location
        double longitude = location.getLongitude(); // Getting longitude of the current location
        myPosition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude); // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myPosition, CAMPUS_DEFAULT_ZOOM_LEVEL));//Camera Update method
    }
}
```

For some reason, this is hit or miss. 3 days ago, it was locking on a position that wasn't where I currently was located while for the past 2 days it worked perfectly. No code was changed whatsoever. Could someone please explain what's going on? Any fixes or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because you are using getLastKnownLocation.

> This can be done without starting the provider. Note that this location could be out-of-date, for example if the device was turned off and moved to another location.
>   If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned.

[documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String))

You have to use requestLocation updates if you want to retrieve the user's current documentation.
[requestLocationUpdates documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener))

Comment: I see, but one of the issues seems to be that, it gets my location correctly then it shows my location that I have been an hour back. Is that normal?

Comment: It is normal that the location sometimes is correct, and other times isn't. If another app hasn't requested a location recently, your location will probably be out of date, and other times it will be correct. If however your location is correct, it normally should be correct as well a few minutes later. You should log which Locationprovider gets used, because you use getBestLocationProvider, which might return a different locationprovider each time you call this method, and could a higher or lower accuracy and because of this a different location.

Comment: Is there a way to camera lock on the googlemap.setmyLocationEnabled programatically?

Comment: I think the map already gets centered on the users current location, if you use setMyLocationEnabled. You can probably find similar questions on this site, or else you should create a new question. If my answer answered your initial question, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Figured it out. setMyLocationEnabled only showed the current position and didn't center. There is a way to call a UI button but that button could not have been accessed programatically.

Thanks for the help :)